# Western Digital Elements 1TB USB3.0 Spins up and then beeps?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery, hard-drive-failure

Well, today, I unplugged my WD external HDD from my laptop so that I could move it to a different port. I was not using any program that would be accessing the drive at the time. However, when I plugged it back in, I hear no spin up, and a "clunk" - stuck heads, so I gave it some "gentle persuasion" (hit it very gently against my palm while it was trying to spin up, and I then managed to get it spinning, However, now when I power the drive up, It spins up, and I then hear beeping (hardware) and then it spins back down. Windows recognises the drive, as I can see it in device manager, however, It doesn't recognise it as a mountable volume :/ Is there any way I'm getting my data back without going to a scam called data recovery?

Comment: Check the connections. Try a different USB cable. If your warranty is up, take it out of the case and put it in a HDD dock station or into a desktop and see if it works. When you say it's recognized, do you see it in Explorer?

Comment: You will need to get access to it first and read from it, before you can do any file copy operations. You should have already done so the last time, when it started working again, after you gave it a "jump start". You should not have continued using it as if nothing happened. But I assume you have some sort of backup of these files? No?

Comment: Hard disk drives don't beep. The beep you hear is probably coming from the circuit-board on the inside of the housing/case/enclosure. It tells you that something is not right, it could mean a bad connection, or just about anything. I was unable to locate any documentation on WDC website about any special beep codes. What model is this? If you could provide model number that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The 'beep' could be coming from the disk read/write head voice coil mechanism or its drive circuitry - that's the bits that move the position of the read/write head array. What you could be hearing is the high current, high frequency drive signal, and it may indicate that either the mechanism is stuck or that it's trying to position the read/write heads somewhere valid, but it can't because there's been a media or electronic failure and its not 'seeing' any data.

Either way, this is not a good sign. Try the diagnostics suggested and if necessary, RMA the drive if it's under warranty.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see the drive mounted to a drive letter in Explorer?
Can you read its contents? Or is the ability to eject it (removable drive) that you don't have now?

If you don't see it in Explorer, run diskmgmt.msc and verify that it's available. How does it look like? Do you see the partitions in there? Or is it just shown as unallocated space? Maybe even shown as not initiated?

In Windows, you have **diskmgmt.msc** and you have **chkdsk**. These are the tools you would use for general disk maintenance, diagnostics and file system repair. I would suggest you write a bootable **Gparted Live** system and boot the computer off of that, and see if you can read the contents of the disk. You can also use any **Linux Live** system for the same purpose.

If you can't read it in either Windows or Linux, and your warranty is expired, I would suggest your take the disk drive out of the housing/case and connect it to a desktop computer. See if you can read it that way. It could be a connection problem. You should have tested another USB cable already, before you do any of this.

---

Official troubleshooting guide can be found on WDC website. You might find these links helpful.

- [WD external drive is not assigned a drive letter by Windows or Mac
  OSX and data on the drive is inaccessible](http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/search/1/a_id/1164/c/130/p/228,219,290)
- [How to test a drive for problems using Data Lifeguard Diagnostics
  for Windows](http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/940/p/228,219,290/session/L3RpbWUvMTQwMDYyNDIyNC9zaWQvS1I2cGxNVWw=)
- [How to get an RMA, (Return Merchandise Authorization) or replace a
  defective product under warranty](http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8/p/228,219,290/session/L3RpbWUvMTQwMDYyNDIyNC9zaWQvS1I2cGxNVWw=)